# TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null - MockedProvider from @apollo/client/testing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, apollo-client, ts-jest

Cant seem to import `MockedProvider` from [@apollo/client/testing](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/) in typescript jest. Looked around and saw this usually occurs with circular dependencies but haven't been able to find any occurrence in my test.

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

      1 | import 'react-native';
      2 | import React from 'react';
    > 3 | import { MockedProvider, MockedResponse } from '@apollo/client/testing';
        | ^
      4 | 
      5 | import renderer from '@tv/test-utils/renderWithProviders';
      6 | import { GetProfileDocument, User } from '@tv/types';

      at Object.__extends (../node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:70:19)
      at ../node_modules/@apollo/client/testing/react/MockedProvider.js:8:5
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@apollo/client/testing/react/MockedProvider.js:32:2)
      at Object.<anonymous> (pages/ProfilePage/ProfilePage.spec.tsx:3:1)
```

**ProfilePage.spec.tsx** - results in above error

```js
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { MockedProvider, MockedResponse } from '@apollo/client/testing';

describe('Profile Page', () => {
    it('console logs', () => {
        console.log(MockedProvider);
    });
});
```

These are the relevant dependencies I'm using:

```
"react-native": "0.64.3",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"@apollo/client": "^3.5.10",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"jest-expo": "^44.0.1",
"@babel/core": "~7.17.9",
"ts-jest": "^26.5.6",
"ts-node": "^10.8.1",
"typescript": "~4.6.3",
```

```
node version: v14.18.1
npm version: 6.14.15
```

**jest.config.ts**

```js
import { pathsToModuleNameMapper } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import ts from 'typescript';

const compilerOptions = ts.readConfigFile('tsconfig.json', ts.sys.readFile)
    .config.compilerOptions;

const moduleMap = pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths);

export default {
    preset: 'jest-expo',
    moduleNameMapper: moduleMap,
    moduleDirectories: [
        '.',
        'src',
        'src/components',
        'src/hooks',
        'node_modules',
    ],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
    rootDir: 'src',
    testRegex: '.*\\.spec\\.(t|j)sx?$',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\.svg$': 'jest-svg-transformer',
    },
    collectCoverageFrom: ['**/*.(t|j)sx?'],
    coverageDirectory: '../coverage',
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        'node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base)',
    ],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/test-utils/mock-modules.js'],
};
```